# Backslash before an argument or value

Tags: php

The title is a bit vague, but i don't know how to express the thought in one sentence:

I just stumbled across these two lines here:

```
catch (\Exception $e)
```

and

```
return new \SFW();
```

What exactly is this backslash doing there? I've never seen or used it in any of my projects and wondering what is the usage of it.

Comment: Read about `namespaces`

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the namespace syntax and allows you to refer to items in the global namespace from within a local namespace. See http://php.net/namespaces. E.g.:

```
namespace Foo;

class Exception { }

new Exception;  // Foo\Exception
new \Exception; // global Exception
```

Comment: Aaah ... somehow, I always managed it to avoid them, I've used namespaces since 5.4 but never used this syntax. Thanks a lot.